# Terraria Invalid Housing?

Tags: terraria

Alright, so I made this really nice house in Terraria, I'll provide pictures to help. So the left side of the house says the housing is valid and the left side is symmetrical to the right side exactly. But the right side says the housing is invalid! I'm super confused of what might be happening...

[image]

I'm currently standing in the right side where it says invalid housing, but directly on the left side it's valid housing and someone is living in it too.

Comment: Is there a chair in that room?

Comment: Also how is there two people living in the same room? (2nd from the top on the left)

Comment: @Aequitas - it looks like the game is trying to center the icon for the room that curves around the left of the building.  Just a quirk of a non-square room I think.

Answer (score 1):

From your picture, it looks like the only stipulation you might be violating is the [Corruption limit](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Home#Corruption_Limit). That side of your house might be too close to the Corruption. As a test, try making a small house down on the ground to the right of your current house and then check if it is valid housing.